# Jtable retain column width

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtableheader, preferredsize

I've a Jtable in which i'm setting data using setDataVector function.It's working fine but suppose if i have changed some column width simply by dragging using mouse and after that new data loads in the same table then the width of that column reset to it's default position.So basically i want to retain that width even if new data loads.

Comment: I'm using a custom tablemodel

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use the setDataVector() method the structure of the table may change so the table automatically recreates the TableColumnModel and you lose your customization.

When you create the JTable the first time use code like:

```
JTable table = new JTable(...);
table.setAutoCreateColumnsFromModel( false );
```

to prevent the TableColumnModel from being recreated.

Comment: Thanks for the help ,I have tried to use setAutoCreateColumnsFromModel() but after this change i'm getting a blank table.Also i'm using a custom table model for Jtable.

Comment: @avinash, `i'm getting a blank table.` its a simple solution, but since you still haven't accepted answers from any of your previous questions I'm not about to spend time helping someone who doesn't appreciate the help.

Comment: oh sorry i was not aware of this " accepting answer" thing.I'll try to take care  of this in the future.

Comment: @avinash, make sure you add the TableModel to the table before using the method I suggested otherwise the table will contain 0 columns.

Answer (score 1):

That happens because when you use [`setDataVector()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#setDataVector%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) according to docs that recreates columns and your column width changes to default.

Try to use [`setAutoCreateColumnsFromModel()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setAutoCreateColumnsFromModel%28boolean%29) to prevent that behavior.

Answer (score 0):

As you use a custom table model. Don't use setDateVector() it recreates the columns. You can manage width of column using setPreferredWidth() method manually as:

```
      table.setModel(buildTableModel(rs));
      TableColumnModel tcm = table.getColumnModel();
      tcm.getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(80);  
      tcm.getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(200);  
      tcm.getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(100);  
      tcm.getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(100);  
      tcm.getColumn(4).setPreferredWidth(100);
```